# Personnage class, vanilla javascript error for write function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem for make a function with ES6 format, on my move function I have this error but I want do like this :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

If you want other part of my code tell me.

```
class Personnage {

  constructor(direction) {
    this.x = 0
    this.y = 200
    this.direction = direction

  }

  move = (direction) => {
    let coord = {
      'x': this.x,
      'y': this.y
    };
    switch (direction) {
      case DIRECTION.GAUCHE:
        coord.x--
          console.log('gauche')
        break;
      case DIRECTION.DROITE:
        coord.x++
          console.log('droite')
        break;
      case DIRECTION.HAUT:
        console.log('espace')
        coord.y--
          break;
    }
    return coord;
  }
}

export default Personnage
```

Comment: `move = (direction)` remove `=`  use `move(direction)`

Answer (score 2):

That code isn't in "ES6" (ES2015) format. To write a method in the `Personnage` class, you'd do this:

```
move(direction) {
    // ...code here...
}
```

Your code **is** in a form that's [being considered for addition](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It's currently at Stage 3 ([see here](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) for what the stages mean), meaning it's likely to be added at some point, and it's very commonly supported by transpilers like Babel, but it's not part of JavaScript yet (not ES2015 aka "ES6", nor ES2016, ES2017, or the upcoming ES2018).

The difference between

```
// #1
move(direction) {
    // ...code here...
}
```

and

```
// #2
move = (direction) => {
    // ...code here...
};
```

(note the `;` at the end) is #1 uses *method syntax* which creates the method on the prototype to be shared by all instances, whereas #2 is an *instance property initializer* using an arrow function, which creates a new arrow function for each instance (as though it were in the constructor). This can matter when you call the method (method syntax uses the `this` it's called with, arrow functions don't, they use the `this` they close over).

Answer (score 1):

The `move = (direction) => {` part is wrong. You must write it like this:

```
class Personnage {

    constructor(direction) { ... }

    move(direction) { /* code goes here */ }
}
```